# C# error : when i create .mdf database backup

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, backup

I am trying to make a backup file using this :

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection.ConnectionString);
 string fname = ofd.FileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + " - " + 
 DateTime.Now.ToString("ss-mm-hh");                
 con.Open();
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"backup database [" + System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\ManageArtsDB.mdf] to disk ='" + fname + ".bak'with init,stats=10", con);
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
 con.Close();
 MessageBox.Show("Backup database was successfull", "Back", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
```

> The error i get :  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "Database"
>   'C:\Users\Khalid\Desktop\ManageTrainingArtsF\ManageTrainingArts\bin\Debug\ManageArtsDB.mdf'
>   does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

the database ManageArtsDB.mdf exist :( but it say its not !

Comment: `backup database` expects the name of the database not its physical path E.g.  `backup database [ManageArtsDB] to ...`  (`con`/`cmd` should be in `using()` blocks)

Comment: My database is local db when i use the line : string strQuery = "Backup database ManageArtsDB to disk = '" + fname + ".bak'"; i got error also :(

Comment: You move the code in another Drive and check once. if any Permission issue in for accessing in c drive or Desktop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to backup a SQL Server 2014 Express Localdb (.mdf) file programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35788119/how-to-backup-a-sql-server-2014-express-localdb-mdf-file-programmatically)

Comment: Done ,, I just deleted the database .. create new local db .. new dataset .. ok